# How to configure user information returned from wso2 is during openid login

Tags: wso2, openid, wso2-identity-server

I'm configured my application (Liferay) to use WSO2 IS (5.1.0) as OpenID server. 
On WSO2 IS side I'm using Resident Identity Provider (so, did not configured any new IDP).

Login via OpenId working quite fine, but only problem - then user logged in only http://axschema.org/namePerson/last claim is returned back to application.
[image]

Question - how can I configure list of claims returned to application during OpenID login?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the claim configuration of the SP in IS for liferay? There can be multiple reasons for claims not returning. Incorrect claim configuration at SP, user claims being empty

Comment: Does OpenID (not OpenID Connect) used Service Provider configuration?

Comment: Actually, the SP claim configuration determines which claims are to be returned about the authenticated user to the SP app. So yes.